# inclusion-exclusion: class distribution so that professor teaches the same two courses both semesters

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> How many ways are there to assign each of five professors in a math department to two courses in the fall semester (i.e., $10$ different math courses in all) and then assign each professor two courses in the spring semester such that no professor teaches the same two courses both semesters?

My answer is:

$ P(C(10,2),5) - C(5,1) \cdot 10 \cdot P(C(9,2),4) + C(5,2) \cdot (10 \cdot 9) \cdot P(C(8,2),3) - ... $

And I am wrong. Why am I wrong? You have 10 courses, and 5 professors are supposed to pick one combination of the courses such that (fall, spring) - so it's $P(C(10,2),5)$. By excluding each case of one professor having the same courses for two semesters in a row, it becomes the following sections of the equation $ - C(5,1) \cdot 10 \cdot P(C(9,2),4) + C(5,2) \cdot (10 \cdot 9) \cdot P(C(8,2),3)$ and so on.

What's wrong with this logic?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327931/assign-n-professors-to-2n-courses-in-two-semesters-and-in-spring-no-professor-te) should help you.

Comment: @ThomasBladt no... not really...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of ways five professors can each be assigned two courses in the fall semester is 
$$\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$$
To see this, list the professors in some order, say by seniority.  Assign the first professor on the list two of the ten courses, which leaves eight courses available.  Assign the next professor on the list two of the remaining eight courses and so forth.

We need to multiply this by the number of ways of assigning each professor two courses in the spring semester without assigning any of those professors the same two courses that the professor taught in the fall semester.

A professor teaches the same two courses both semesters:  There are five ways to choose which professor is assigned the same two courses that he or she taught in the fall semester.  The remaining eight courses are distributed among the remaining four professors in 
$$\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$$
ways.  Thus, there are 
$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$$
such spring semester assignments.

There are 
$$\binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$$ 
ways to assign two professors to teach the same two courses they taught in the fall semester.

There are 
$$\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$$
ways to assign three professors to teach the same two courses they taught in the fall semester.

There are 
$$\binom{5}{4}\binom{2}{2}$$
ways to assign four professors to teach the same two courses they taught in the fall semester.

There are 
$$\binom{5}{5}$$
ways to assign all five professors to teach the same two courses they taught in the fall semester.

By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of admissible spring semester teaching assignments is 
$$\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2} - \binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2} + \binom{5}{4}\binom{2}{2} - \binom{5}{5}$$
Therefore, the number of ways five professors can each be assigned two courses in the fall semester and two courses in the spring professor so that no professor teaches the same two courses both semesters is 
$$\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}\left[\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2} - \binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2} + \binom{5}{4}\binom{2}{2} - \binom{5}{5}\right]$$

Comment: This answers so many questions I had. Thank you so much.

Comment: One minor question: why multiply by $10!/2!2!2!2!2!$? I'm only 70% sure about this

Comment: The question asks how many ways five professors can be assigned two courses each during the fall semester and then be assigned two courses each in the spring semester so that none of them teaches the same two courses they taught in the fall semester.  The factor outside the brackets is the number of ways they can be assigned to teach classes in the fall semester.  The factor inside the brackets is the number of ways they can be assigned to teach classes in the spring semester in such a way that no professor teaches the same two classes as in the fall semester.